# JFrame scrollable HTML content

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe, scrollbar

I have a fix height JFrame displaying HTML code and I want it to dispaly a scrollbar when the HTML content height exceeds the JFrame height. How would I do that? I have this code so far:

```
public class Pupup extends JPanel {

  public Pupup() {
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    String initialText = "<html>" +
      "<body>" +
      "</body>" +
      "</html>";

    theLabel = new JLabel(initialText) {
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(640, 480);
      }
      public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(640, 480);
      }
      public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return new Dimension(640, 480);
      }
    };

    theLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    theLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);

    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    JPanel PANEL = new JPanel();
    PANEL.setLayout(new BoxLayout(PANEL, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    PANEL.add(theLabel);
    PANEL.add(pane);
    add(PANEL);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use BoxLayout when you intend to use entire size of the JFrame for displaying html content.

First put your HTML widget into JScrollPane.
Then add this JScrollPane as only item in your main panel. You can use GridLayout(1,1) for the main panel.
Then do frame.setContentPane(mainPanel).

Comment: Could you please give me an example on how I would do that? Thanks